# Getting php data from admin panel, without inserting in database and sessions

Tags: php

I have a website and an administrator panel. I need to take some data from the administrator panel fields and show it on the homepage.

For example: on the homepage there is a `text block` and on the administrator panel there is a `input` form. I fill it in, press submit, it saves everything (shows current text on form and on homepage). With a database it would be very easy, but this time I can't use database. Is there any alternative choice that I could use instead of saving it to a database?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, what do you mean by `it saves everything`? Why can't you use a database? With the correct permission I guess you could store and retreive data from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in a flat (normal) text file, and later retrieve it using the `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` functions.

If you compile the details you wish to store into an array, you can then use `serialize()` to convert that array into a simple string, which would make it alot easier to store more than one piece of information with the text files mentioned above.

That being said, a database is often the best solution for storing alot of data (as the name would suggest), so if that requirement/limitation can be revisited, all the better.

Comment: Hello, I was already thinking of text file, but it won't be able same as database. Is there anything else, taht could make me happy? :)

Comment: "but it won't be able same as database"? If you make your requirements clearer, maybe I can assist further. You might also be able to use SQLite rather than MySQL if you still want to use a database-centric solution.

Comment: Hello, hmm, well, I need to make it as easy as possible, so there wouldn't be any new files created or customer won't need to create database. It would be perfect, if he would just go inside, write in all data, save and they would automatically save "Somewhere"...
Well, but probably currently, the best idea sounds, creating new file, since it will take less time from customer, than creating a database.

Comment: Needs will vary dependent on your users' level of skills. If they can FTP files onto a server, being able to provision a basic database/user and then enter that into an Install process (like what you see when you install Wordpress, or any database-driven Open Source product) is not an unrealistic expectation. Look at the install processes/scripts for these products and use them as a guide for building.